# Сортировка элементов структуры типа string c++

Tags: c++, строки, функции, сортировка, структуры

Не знаю какой должная быть ф-ия, которая принимает массив структур и сортирует его по одному элементу типа string, да ещё и по алфавиту. Может кто подсказать?

```
struct AEROFLOT
{
public:
char Trip[20];      //номер рейса
string Departure;  // пункт отправления
string Destination;  //пункт назначения <--- по этому элементу нужно отсортировать массив
char Type[30];  //тип самолёта
float Time;  //Время в пути
float Price; / / цена билета
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AEROFLOT a[N];

sort(a,a+N,[](const AEROFLOT& x,const AEROFLOT& y)
{ return x.Destination < y.Destination; });
```

Где-то так...

Comment: Можете объяснить что тут происходит?

Comment: Сортировка N элементов массива с использованием компаратора, который сравнивает только поле Destination...

Comment: какая библиотека?

Comment: немного непонятно как аэрофлот может иметь пункт отправления и пункт назначения.  Скорее нужно было назвать класс расписанием

Comment: Стандартная библиотека C++

Comment: работает только при `#include <algorithm>`
Можете объяснить как именно работает каждая ф-ия?

Comment: Вам как - полностью, до строчки расписывать, как именно работает `sort` или достаточно просто сказать, что она сортирует с использованием пользовательского компаратора? :) Вот - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort. Компаратор перед вами - что тут еще расписывать?!

Comment: не дружу с буржуйским, но это на этом спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Пояснительный код к ответу от Harry:

```
bool cmpByDeparture (const AEROFLOT& r1, const AEROFLOT& r2)
{
    return r1.Departure < r2.Departure;
}

bool cmpByDestination(const AEROFLOT& r1, const AEROFLOT& r2)
{
    return r1.Destination < r2.Destination;
}
//...
AEROFLOT a[N];
sort(a,a+N, cmpByDestination); //  сортировка по пункту назначения
sort(a,a+N, cmpByDeparture);   //  по пункту отправления
```

просто вместо того, чтоб отдельно написать функцию, была использована лямбда